# Why are GridSearchCV metrics different to mine on the same fold (scikit)?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I implemented a custom scorer function which prints a `classification_report` and `confusion_matrix`on `y_true, y_predicted` of `GridSearchCV` on a predefined fold. I then ran these metrics on the same fold outside `GridSearchCV` using the model generated by `GridSearchCV`. The reports are different. Why?

[Folder with dataset and Jupyter notebook](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0yzduQbkhXxYBBkec8EIt42fA#PA6)

Relevant sections are "Train/Test Split" and "Investigation". Otherwise, the code is below:

**Train/Test Split**

```
train_i = np.full((int(data.shape[0] * (1 - test_size)),), -1, dtype=int)
test_i  = np.full((int(data.shape[0] * test_size,)), 0, dtype=int)

train_test_i = np.append(train_i, test_i)

np.random.shuffle(train_test_i)
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import PredefinedSplit

ps = PredefinedSplit(train_test_i)
```

```
for train_index, test_index in ps.split(data):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
```

```
test_set = data.iloc[test_index]
y_test = test_set['Category']

X_test = X_tf.tocsr()[test_index,:]
```

**Training**

```
# custom scorer

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def my_scorer(y_true, y_predicted):

    print(classification_report(y_true, y_predicted))
    print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_predicted))

    global y_predicted

    return accuracy_score(y_true, y_predicted)

my_func = make_scorer(my_scorer)
```

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
mnb = MultinomialNB()
mnb.fit(X_tf, y)
```

```
tuned_parameters = [
    {'alpha': [1.0]
    }]

nb = GridSearchCV(MultinomialNB(), tuned_parameters, scoring = my_func, cv = ps)

nb.fit(X_tf, y)
```

````
# test accuracy
test_pred = nb.predict(X_test)

print(classification_report(y_test, test_pred))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, test_pred))
```
````

Comment: can you provide a reproducible code?

Comment: I am working on a data set in a Jupyter. May I upload a compressed folder comprised of the notebook and the data set?

Comment: it'll be better if you put your code within ```<code yere>``` segments, and add a link to your uploaded data in the post. Only the code might suffice as well by the way. Not all solutions need the data.

Comment: Please see question edit above. And thank you for attending to it.